# Divide time range to N equal duration

Tags: python, time-series

we're given a stating and ending time (let say st_time = 05:00 and en_time = 23:00) and the task is to divide this time to N equal duration.

if N=6 then output should look like this
(05:00 , 08:00 , 11:00 , 14:00 , 17:00 , 20:00 , 23:00)

I'm expecting python code for this problem statement.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and the error or problem you are facing.

Comment: Start by describing the steps you would take to do this by hand. Don't worry about python syntax. Just use English words.

Comment: Given the task, are you expecting a result to be N tuples of length 2 with a start and end timestamp or an ordered list of indexes for a DataFrame, divided into N equal parts?

Comment: ending time minus starting time, then divide by n should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This would solve your question in a matter you described

```py
import datetime
st_time = '05:00'
en_time = '23:00'
N = 6


def split_interval_to_list(start_string: str, end_string: str, n_parts: int = 2, format_string: str = '%H:%M') -> tuple:
    """split interval into N parts, giving a tuple of times

    Args:
        start_string (str): start time as string
        end_string (str): end time as string
        n_parts (int, optional): numper of pieces. Defaults to 2.
        format_string (str, optional): format string. Defaults to '%H:%M'.

    Returns:
        tuple: tuple of times, including beginning and end
    """
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_string, format_string)
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_string, '%H:%M')

    delta = end - start
    if n_parts is None or n_parts == 1:
        return (start.strftime('%H:%M'), end.strftime('%H:%M'))

    result = [(start + (delta/n_parts) * i).strftime('%H:%M')
              for i in range(n_parts)]
    result.append(end.strftime('%H:%M'))
    result_tuple = tuple(result)
    return result_tuple


split_interval_to_list(st_time, en_time, N)
```

Which results in a tuple with beginning and end of time period:

```bash
('05:00', '08:00', '11:00', '14:00', '17:00', '20:00', '23:00')
```

Comment: Great documentation and idiomatic solution!